# Is the variance a suitable measure of variability in this context?

Tags: variance, count-data, excel, range

A rather basic question, prefaced by the fact that I know just enough about statistics to be dangerous.

I work with Air Force Technical Training.  I am trying to compare the ebb and flow of students in a particular course throughout the year with the average number of students in that course per day. Sometimes the actual number of students is above the average line, sometimes below.  Is calculating the standard deviation an adequate way to measure the variability, or is there a better way?  Google is my friend, so if anyone can point me to a better test to use I should be able to find it.  However, note that I am limited to what I can do in Excel.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you may be interested in techniques from Statistical Process Control (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control), in particular the "X Bar Chart" may be appropriate for your problem. (PS: in your only sentence ending in a question mark, you should change "variance" to "variation" or some wise-butt is going to point out that variance and standard deviation are equivalent notions).

Comment: Thanks, was going to make the edit but the site said someone named utobi edited my post and my change isn't different enough?  Oh well, I'm learning..  I'll check out the link you provided and let you know if it helped.

Comment: (here's a link for the X bar chart in particular: https://sixsigmastudyguide.com/x-bar-r-control-charts/)

Comment: Gerry I made some edits to your post and to the title. Feel free to apply your changes if you wish.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the number of students is (at least in principle) bounded and I don't see any reason to think that the daily number of students comes from some heavy-tailed distribution.
Therefore, I don't see any counter effects in using the standard deviation as a measure of variability. By the way, the standard deviation is also commonly used in Statistical Process Control (suggested in the comments by [John Madden](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/82893/john-madden).)

Comment: We get our students from a prerequisite course which we don't control the schedule of.  Thus we don't get an even flow of students throughout the year.  For example if we start 10 classes a year, which are long enough that often 2 or 3 classes overlap, our enrollment might look like 14, 28,16, 43, etc.  Does this help?

Comment: Sure, you can calculate the SD, but there could be several obstacles to *interpreting* a standard deviation.  Most of them are related to the possibility of serial correlation or other forms of lack of independence among class sizes.  Why not recommend the simple approach of *plotting the class size over time* and just looking at the plot?

Comment: @whuber I fully agree with you, graphical analysis goes first and foremost. I was limiting my answer to the specific query raised by the OP, but expanding it a bit in this respect won't do any harm. I'll update my post. Thank you for the suggestion!